# Azure performance issue using Trace

Tags: .net, azure, trace

I've built an API and deployed to Azure. Getting some really bad performance so did a super basic test. A simple return, then I used Azures own Performance test.

Both tests are done by 5 minutes, target load: 250. As you can see of the tests there's a vast difference in performance. I'm I doing something really wrong? I've enabled Application Insights and turned off Diagnostics Logs. Nothing specified in web.config

Test 1.
**SUCCESS** 68,681 (100 %)
**FAILED** 0 (0 %)

**AVG. RESP TIME (SEC)** 0,08
**USER LOAD** 250 REQ/SEC
**REQ/SEC** 228,94

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("messages2")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMessages2()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "hello");
}
```

Test 2.
**SUCCESS** 8,688 (100 %)
**FAILED** 0 (0 %)

**AVG. RESP TIME (SEC)** 7,49
**USER LOAD** 250 REQ/SEC
**REQ/SEC** 28,96

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("messages2")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMessages2()
{
    Stopwatch timespan = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    timespan.Stop();
    log.TraceApi("ApiMessage", "v1_MessageController.GetMessages2", timespan.Elapsed);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "hello");
}
```

The trace class is a simple

```
Trace.TraceInformation(message);
```

**MORE TESTS**

I deleted everything in azure and re-created to make sure everything is in the same region. Now I'm getting a response time of **average 0.2**, that is a big difference. And this is running my full function with Redis get/set and database requests. These were about **23.0**.

--updated-- THIS is false, I forgot to enable application logging.
So now I'm enable verbose application log to a storage and the average time goes up to **0.33**. How can I use logging but not impact the service so much?

Comment: Which trace listener do you use? BTW:`Trace` static class is deprecated and you should use `TraceSource` to configure a logger.

Comment: Using Trace, will try out TraceSource and see if that will improve the log performance.

Comment: TraceSource doesn't work well with Azure logging, Trace is better. When using trace I get traces mapped with Application Insight calls.

Comment: My bad. it does. It takes a little while for AI to gather log info and combine it.